# Angular transform data with NgStyle and property Binding (or sth else)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

im learning programming in Angular and i have a problem with property Bindings. But first the part of my code:

```
// TS FILE

data[
{"id": "1", "name": "tester", "rev": "1"},
{"id": "2", "name": "tester", "rev": "1"},
{"id": "3", "name": "tester", "rev": "1"},
];


createNumberArray(): number[] {
// code to fill array
return anyArrayOfNumbers
}
```

```
<div  *ngFor="let datas of data; let i = index" >


    <ul>
  <li class='list-item' [id]= datas.id [ngStyle]="{ 'transform': 'rotate( numberArray[i] deg) translate(0,-100px) rotate(-numberArray[i]deg)' }">
     <!-- how it would work: <li class='list-item' [id]= datas.id [ngStyle]="{ 'transform': 'rotate(200deg) translate(0,-100px) rotate(-150deg)' }"> -->
            <div class='label1'><img alt='notfound' class='img2' src='any icon'></div>
            <div class='label2'>
                {{ datas.name }}
            </div>
            <div class='label3'>
                {{ datas.id }}
            </div>
            <div class='label4'>
                {{ datas.rev }}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The data property contains an Array of Objects and i want to list every Object with his name, id and rev. I can display them, but now i also want them to rotate dynamically. So i created a new Array of numbers, which is coming from an function called createNumberArray(). And these numbers shall tell the ngStyle for each loop run which number he shall take to rotate. This is how i wanted to be it:

```
<li class='list-item' [id]= datas.id [ngStyle]="{ 'transform': 'rotate( numberArray[i] deg) translate(0,-100px) rotate(-numberArray[i]deg)' }">
```

But thats not working cause i can´t get it managed to work, i tryed it with with property binding, but never got the number out of the array inside the transform.
And thats the code how it would work (with just the same number all the time):

```
<!-- how it would work: <li class='list-item' [id]= datas.id [ngStyle]="{ 'transform': 'rotate(200deg) translate(0,-100px) rotate(-150deg)' }"> -->
```

I managed to get this work with Js, Jquery and html but now i want to do it with Angular. And also without Jquery, so i dont just copy past my old code. But im a bit confused about if i should use Jquery in Angular in the future. Whats the best way to manupulate the DOM, what do you guys think?

I would really appreciate your help. Im already thankful that you took the time to read my question.

Comment: You probably need something like `'... rotate(-' + numberArray[i] + 'deg) ...'` since you're within an expression. But where is `createNumberArray` called?

Comment: @Jeto That was also my first taught, that theres maybe some wrong quote sign. But my problem is the one to call createNumberArray() in the html file. I wanted to call it like `*ngFor let numbers of createNumberArray`, but didnt work. So i tryed sth like `numberArray = [createNumberArray()]` and so on, but no one worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set the array values in constructor:

**Typescript:**

```
  ...
  anyArrayOfNumbers: number[] = [];
  constructor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
      this.anyArrayOfNumbers.push(200);
    }
  }

  getNumberArray(index): number {
    return this.anyArrayOfNumbers[index];
  }
```

Then call getNumberArray from html the method:

**HTML**

```
...[ngStyle]="{ 'transform': 'rotate('+numberArray[i]+'deg) translate(0,-100px) rotate('+numberArray[i]+'deg)' } ...
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qg16h1)**

Comment: My actual problem was how to get numberArray from the createNumberArray() of the TS file into the html file. Sry for being imprecise, but can you tell me pls how to get this array of numbers?

Comment: I am not sure to understand well. Is this demo close what you are looking for? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxwsyt

Comment: Thats the way i wanted it to work, but with a differerent way: `public anyArrayOfNumbers: number[];
  getNumberArray(i): number {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length;i++){
      this.anyArrayOfNumbers[i] = 100;
    }
    return this.anyArrayOfNumbers[i];
  }` If i try it like this, i always call a property of 0, so i tryed to call the method from constructor or onInit, but same problem. My Array never gets filled if i call the method in html.

Comment: I arranged your code to make it work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qg16h1?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Glad to hear that :)